# Typescript generic type with an attribute that acts as a key for subsequent data not working in a union type

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here is a [typescriptlang playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgBA4gpgdlBOBDALlAJmZBPADlAzmAGbwD2AtmDmcqUQJYA2UYaUDMy9pMhAbvUSYAxtVK0wIYACgoADxyl4yMPU4IiiYSwASURGkZqoAERRCA3tLA2w5KMkQAuMCfaIAro2QBZB0IAfMA8YNg50AG5rWxRkeHoAIw9UfBc9AyM4AEFkOMTkgjAgkLDjNCiAX2lZBSUVNVR4TW0wdMNjHLyklLArWzAAC2RyRgAVemRmF3w8mABzKP6hkYBlDwSuSagAfmnZuaLg0PYyyur5RWVVdSatFlH5ZDNHXuibe0cXN00vX39DkonODlN5gWLxboEFwPOTIToQgqEYrHcIgqo1S71G7Ne6PeH5Hp9WzLMaPPbxeZnDF1a6NHGudy-PwvIk2RiILCkZIABVI+Am3Bg5LUC2k6IuNIaGjuYAAwhRFHBOAAlAiK-AsVmYXBQYWU0Focy7XpgAAkwkQGpcACIBvp2nBrRFBvbMrrWq7jM8hBVDhYzRarWBrahYU7MGSwDCnuYwBUzqBILAECh0GBYBgpNVpMBgFGdZgBihWEDCsg7WBhAqeLAVDN4B5hMgPPAWB5+fNCyw5smkKgMNg8Pgc3mAKJ8BBYSvVpUqIuEIQAA0HUEXYAA7gN6MIBmCmwuF2AANZQKdqMCLw2ORcAOgv5stq9UhB7cD7aYSU+QohopDBoRdRgcEIc9ShgEUu21PA71GP9yEQE8920fBCH0fkEAAGjAABJDdEE4TA-yLCdIIfDUwD4RBGA8Fhz2XHVF2pK4VzlGda2w7E7gAHnlchFVrAA5RB7HTWEM0IVUAEcPHoVs0B4tiVTVHgNQAPgAbQAcivRBNIAXS0sioH01SwAAXlefoVxcXj+M4IT7Awg1zBsxTkAclhHnE49TzoMBR1hJAmy4qSZLkhS+JrJT8HVKANO08x9Kw-0jNcyLZw8uNTO2MAAHlyAmLiAriLRkBCqBpNk9AIrs5BVRilS4q0nSkpNVLWPSwThJYCpVKwzSjM00yXDgCd4DFapcxwyt8JLcJMHXP8q06zgFwAqjGDBXIEVQIREFba4iAQNMq3gVsm0YLBpCrXgVFDZA0tqji6W4zT7qG8zLNsaywDex5NKc-odJcLUrMjUH+hibaCShL7Ifh4lhlJWEXE06MAdBBG40BrHbA+Zw4dx-p2U5Hk+QFHhUfgtQMaJmwKhx+GGdBZn42qG6ZhdDJjEeqLkGe6VtC4zS7W5uAPosrUfpFz1xcZ1gXMJpZZfdCH4fBGHUiVumSXGLZUbaN1abppYkbWDYJimX7zc2ZhNMxhHmZN-GQYdomSa5ZBeX5LhKd+6mYGNomqixkPbCqdEptwi0YCQghCHIKcdIowRIPovA1x4MFpxW5BrpU0hmBvRhSDmAAKe6bx09TK5XPSbw1yF8G2G9dceABKKIOcLqBi9LsvRYdXvq8Ht0bzrhvoablvdctqBO8mvMsiOQUoJYIglDBRhNsUFDEmYHPatrYcWNsvmADV9sQBpCAss-ZwF24hZlsXjNMoJ7-Yzjn-e1TF7ALIsd9pICnOuCYu5E6Hz5sODmKhlq1S1p-Tgl8kA33UnpT6NdHhYVHsYPS-8BKkHXNNCYx1UxgFIGNOwU4jCcz8vA6B-4MBaGQoQcsUBZIKxeGA8s1CLwrjXJabOJ4sB3hMKQAggcVCLXgEefOud8A3ngjgMuZcGGznbuZUyWpu5FxLuXdRtYq7mHUoYzg48dR6QXhUTuQA)

I want to have multiple types which share a similar structure. I call them components. They look like this:

```
{
    type: componentName
    data: {
        [componentName]: {...}
    }
}
```

This structure is necessary because it comes from a `oneOf` proto file definition.
I build a generic which types one component correctly based on a `componentName` and the generated types from proto files.

```
// Type that defines the component structure using the generated types
// Every component has a `type` which acts as a key in `data`. `$case` is generated by tcproto and helps in defining the type.
export type ComponentInterface<ComponentName extends Required<ComponentResponse>['data']['$case']> = {
    type: ComponentName,
    data: ComponentName extends keyof Extract<Required<ComponentResponse>['data'], { $case: ComponentName }> ? Omit<Extract<Required<ComponentResponse>['data'], { $case: ComponentName }>, '$case'> : never
}

// I can define two components and all attributea are infered correctly
const text: ComponentInterface<'text'> = {
    type: 'text',
    data: {
        text: {
            attributes: {
                htmlText: 'Text',
            },
            meta: {
                layoutPosition: 'main',
            },
        },
    },
};

// I can access my data via the `type` on a component without problems
console.log(text.data[text.type].attributes?.htmlText);
```

Now I want to have an array with components of this structure which I can loop through and access their data via the `componentName`. But here stops working my typescript and it throws an error.

```
// A union type for all possible componentents
type ComponentVaraints = ComponentInterface<'headline'> | ComponentInterface<'text'>

// An array with my components
const components: ComponentVaraints[] = [text, headline]

components.map((component) => {
    console.log(component.data[component.type]);
});
```

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"headline" | "text"' can't be used to index type 'Omit<{ $case: "text"; text: TextData; }, "$case"> | Omit<{ $case: "headline"; headline: HeadlineData; }, "$case">'.
> Property 'headline' does not exist on type 'Omit<{ $case: "text"; text: TextData; }, "$case"> | Omit<{ $case: "headline"; headline: HeadlineData; }, "$case">'.

Does anyone have an idea what exactly is my problem? I would think typescript should now that each component is accessible via the `type`.

Answer (score 1):

This result is as expected, because the type of `component` is not determined in `components.map`, just add type judgment:

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgBA4gpgdlBOBDALlAJmZBPADlAzmAGbwD2AtmDmcqUQJYA2UYaUDMy9pMhAbvUSYAxtVK0wIYACgoADxyl4yMPU4IiiYSwASURGkZqoAERRCA3tLA2w5KMkQAuMCfaIAro2QBZB0IAfMA8YNg50AG5rWxRkeHoAIw9UfBc9AyM4AEFkOMTkgjAgkLDjNCiAX2lZBSUVNVR4TW0wdMNjHLyklLArWzAAC2RyRgAVemRmF3w8mABzKP6hkYBlDwSuSagAfmnZuaLg0PYyyur5RWVVdSatFlH5ZDNHXuibe0cXN00vX39DkonODlN5gWLxboEFwPOTIToQgqEYrHcIgqo1S71G7Ne6PeH5Hp9WzLMaPPbxeZnDF1a6NHGudy-PwvIk2RiILCkZIABVI+Am3Bg5LUC2k6IuNIaGjuYAAwhRFHBOAAlAiK-AsVmYXBQYWU0Focy7XpgAAkwkQGpcACIBvp2nBrRFBvbMrrWq7jM8hBVDhYzRarWBrahYU7MGSwDCnuYwBUzqBILAECh0GBYBgpNVpMBgFGdZgBihWEDCsg7WBhAqeLAVDN4B5hMgPPAWB5+fNCyw5smkKgMNg8Pgc3mAKJ8BBYSvVpUqIuEIQAA0HUEXYAA7gN6MIBmCmwuF2AANZQKdqMCLw2ORcAOgv5stq9UhB7cD7aYSU+QohopDBoRdRgcEIc9ShgEUu21PA71GP9yEQE8920fBCH0fkEAAGjAABJDdEE4TA-yLCdIIfDUwD4RBGA8Fhz2XHVF2pK4VzlGda2w7E7gAHnlchFVrAA5RB7HTWEM0IVUAEcPHoVs0B4tiVTVHgNQAPgAbQAcivRBNIAXS0sioH01SwAAXlefoVxcXj+M4IT7Awg1zBsxTkAclhHnE49TzoMBR1hJAmy4qSZLkhS+JrJT8HVKANO08x9Kw-0jNcyLZw8uNTO2MAAHlyAmLiAriLRkBCqBpNk9AIrs5BVRilS4q0nSkpNVLWPSwThJYCpVKwzSjM00yXDgCd4DFapcxwyt8JLcJMHXP8q06zgFwAqjGDBXIEVQIREFba4iAQNMq3gVsm0YLBpCrXgVFDZA0tqji6W4zT7qG8zLNsaywDex5NKc-odJcLUrMjUH+hibaCShL7Ifh4lhlJWEXE06MAdBBG40BrHbA+Zw4dx-p2U5Hk+QFHhUfgtQMaJmwKhx+GGdBZn42qG6ZhdDJjEeqLkGe6VtC4zS7W5uAPosrUfpFz1xcZ1gXMJpZZfdCH4fBGHUiVumSXGLZUbaN1abppYkbWDYJimX7zc2ZhNMxhHmZN-GQYdomSa5ZBeX5LhKd+6mYGNomqixkPbCqdEptwi0YCQghCHIKcdIowRIPovA1x4MFpxW5BrpU0hmBvRhSDmAAKe6bx09TK5XPSbw1yF8G2G9dceABKKIOcLqBi9LsvRYdXvq8Ht0bzrhvoablvdctqBO8mvMsiOQUoJYIglDBRhNsUFDEmYHPatrYcWNsvmADV9sQBpCAss-ZwF24hZlsXjNMoJ7-Yzjn-e1TF7ALIsd9pICnOuCYu5E6Hz5sODmKhlq1S1p-Tgl8kA33UnpT6NdHhYVHsYPS1QiAhCbKveg+Boxl3gXzXms4UHX1Wu3FwlDZzPg6k9b+UBha-0Jq2Zs8BY5MNrOPAsZkRG-XehNEcYABKkHXNNCYx1UxgFIGNOwU4jCcz8gI1a-4MBaGQoQcsUBZIKxeGA8sqiLwrjXJabOJ4sB3hMKQAggcVCLXgEefOud8A3ngjgMuFC3Lt3MqZLU9AiBgDLqQ8hWjkDtyCWracvAe593LjEqu5h1JpLrgvfoEdO5AA)

```
function isText(component: ComponentVaraints): component is ComponentInterface<'text'> {
    return component.type === 'text'
}

components.map((component) => {
    if (isText(component)) {
        console.log(component.data[component.type]);
    }
});
```

Comment: the problem is that I will have a lot of component types. All of them share this base structure and I should be able to access those shared properties without a problem, right?

Comment: If you want to access those shared properties, you should keep the type of the property is same. As this case,  `component.type` should be `string`. As i said above, the type of `component` in `components` is `ComponentInterface<'headline'> | ComponentInterface<'text'>`, you can't know which type it is unless you judge. Think about the error: because expression of type '"headline" | "text"' can't be used to index type 'Omit<{ $case: "text"; text: TextData; }, "$case"> | Omit<{ $case: "headline"; headline: HeadlineData; }, "$case">
···